# http 404 error on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I have found several replicas of this question, but none helped me.
I was dealing with jsp and hibernet with eclipse and apache server. 
The server installation is in port 9090. An downloaded project has imported from `D:/`. 
After clearing the  jre path, I Run the project on server and the out put is error

### `HTTP Status 404 - /servlet/

type Status report
message /servlet/

### description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.32`

The google search gave some remedies and I followed that. The following are the screen shots.

Project:

[image]

Server Properties:

[image]

Tomcat Overview:
[image]

Did I missed anything?

Comment: Which url did you try to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I had made some mistakes
1. I have failed to include the welcome page in web.xml
2. I had put the project in eclipse workspace and I choose the server location as `Use tomcat installation`. That was wrong. I should choose `workspace meta data` as my project is in workspace

Answer (score 0):

Below steps solves 404 problem if server is properly configured.

**First:**

Check your Context root for this project.

You can edit context root from **project-->property->web project settings**.

**Second:**

Restart your server and try to clean and build again. Sometimes that solves 404 problem.

**Third:**

1) Double click on your server or right click->open

2) Click on open launch configuration

3) Go to classpath tab

4) See in user-entries, commons-daemon.jar is available or not if it not then click on add external jar -->   path(which you can find it in TOMCAT_HOME/bin)

5) Click on apply and restart your server

Now access : `http://localhost:9090/<project-context-root>`

Comment: default context root is the project name itself. right?
Here it is servlet. So what should I edit instead of this name?

Comment: You have to edit only if it is different from what you are accessing.I updated my answer with another condition which can solve this problem. It may help you.

Comment: The 3 methods doesn't works for me :(. I could not find the commons-daemon.jar in TOMCAT_HOME/bin. However I had added this as external jar to the user-entries;

Comment: I have this project in eclipse_space. Is there is any problem related to the project location?

Comment: I solved the issue. I had made some mistakes

Comment: This works perfect for me, Thanks

Comment: You can upvote, if this answer solved your need.